# How to retrieve http response body when MS dynamics returns HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: dynamics-crm, olingo

I'm using Olingo client to connect to Microsoft Dynamics 365 V9.0 to update the entities such as account etc.

However, from time to time, the Olingo client(latest 4.4.0) returns ODataServerErrorException with only server status such as "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error". This doesn't tell much of the root cause. What we need is the detailed error messages returned with http response body.
The code snippet and stack trace is as following:

```
try {
        ODataBatchResponse response = batchManager.getAsyncResponse().get(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        ...
} catch (Exception e) {
   log.error("error: "+ e.getMessage(), e)
}
```

the stacktrace:

```
13 Jul 2018 23:56:18,958 ERROR Thread-77378 exportimpl.MicrosoftDynamicsCrmExportJobImpl  - error:  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.olingo.client.api.communication.ODataServerErrorException: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
org.apache.olingo.client.api.http.HttpClientException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.olingo.client.api.communication.ODataServerErrorException: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.AbstractODataStreamManager.getHttpResponse(AbstractODataStreamManager.java:128) ~[odata-client-core-4.4.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.batch.ODataBatchRequestImpl$BatchManagerImpl.getResponseInstance(ODataBatchRequestImpl.java:88) ~[odata-client-core-4.4.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.batch.AbstractBatchManager.getResponse(AbstractBatchManager.java:115) ~[odata-client-core-4.4.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.batch.AbstractBatchManager.getResponse(AbstractBatchManager.java:38) ~[odata-client-core-4.4.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.AbstractODataStreamManager$1.get(AbstractODataStreamManager.java:179) ~[odata-client-core-4.4.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.AbstractODataStreamManager$1.get(AbstractODataStreamManager.java:154) ~[odata-client-core-4.4.0.jar:?]
    at java_util_concurrent_Future$get$0.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
...
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1189.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:495) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.olingo.client.api.communication.ODataServerErrorException: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.AbstractODataStreamManager.getHttpResponse(AbstractODataStreamManager.java:125) ~[odata-client-core-4.4.0.jar:?]
    ... 57 more
Caused by: org.apache.olingo.client.api.communication.ODataServerErrorException: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.header.ODataErrorResponseChecker.checkResponse(ODataErrorResponseChecker.java:74) ~[odata-client-core-4.4.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.AbstractRequest.checkResponse(AbstractRequest.java:54) ~[odata-client-core-4.4.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.AbstractODataRequest.doExecute(AbstractODataRequest.java:310) ~[odata-client-core-4.4.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.batch.ODataBatchRequestImpl.doExecute(ODataBatchRequestImpl.java:73) ~[odata-client-core-4.4.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.streamed.AbstractODataStreamedRequest.access$300(AbstractODataStreamedRequest.java:51) ~[odata-client-core-4.4.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.streamed.AbstractODataStreamedRequest$2.call(AbstractODataStreamedRequest.java:118) ~[odata-client-core-4.4.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.streamed.AbstractODataStreamedRequest$2.call(AbstractODataStreamedRequest.java:115) ~[odata-client-core-4.4.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Web Api endpoint? I would say your security token has expired but this would be an error 401. Since it's 500, the problem would be Dynamics. If you have the request body and header you should open a ticket.

Were you running on v8.2 previously? It could help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Thx Nick! After turned on the httpclient logging, the error message was captured:{"Message":"The server is busy and the request was not completed. Try again later.",...}. The question is how to get the message at run time and and surface it to the caller.